# How to use Angular 1 directive variable inside the Angular 2 component function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

```
var app = angular.module('addApp', []);
app.controller('addController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
}]).directive('add', function(){
    return {
        scope:{},
        template: '<input type="number" ng-model=number>',
        controller: 'addController'
    };
});

var adapter = new ng.upgrade.UpgradeAdapter();

AppComponent = ng.core.Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<add></add>sum={{sum}}',
    directives: [adapter.upgradeNg1Component('add')]
}).Class({
    constructor:function() {
        this.frist=5;
    },
    add():function{
        this.sum=frist+number;
    }
});

app.directive('myApp', adapter.downgradeNg2Component(AppComponent));
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['addApp']);
    console.log(adapter);
});
```

I've upgraded the above Angular 1 code into Angular 2 using UpgradeAdapter.

I want to further write an app using Angular 2. So I want to use input numbers inside the angular component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only possibility is to use interpolation of Angular2 to pass an object of the component to the Angular1 directive so the latter can bind the input against it. Primitive types can't be used at this level since Angular2 directives don't support two way binding on such fields. You need to provide a "container" object for your value, so you can update the container by reference and share data between the Angular1 directive and the Angular2 component.

It's mandatory for this to define a sub scope for your directive in this case. "Scopes" can be shared between Angular1 directives and Angular2 components.

Here is the approach I would recommend:

```
var app = angular.module('addApp', []);
app.controller('addController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

}]).directive('add', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      number: '='
    },
    template: '<input type="number" ng-model="number.value">',
    controller: 'addController'
  };
});
```

The Angular2 component would provide a container for the number:

```
AppComponent = ng.core
.Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <add [number]="number"></add>
    <span (click)="add()">add</span>
    sum={{sum}}
  `,
  directives: [adapter.upgradeNg1Component('add')]
})
.Class({
  constructor:function() {
    this.frist = 5;
    this.number = { value: 10 };
  },
  add() {
    this.sum = this.frist + this.number.value;
  }
});
```

Here is the corresponding plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/M4m4aZMNr3yc7TgMD9Ko?p=preview.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: if number is not input and it is $scope.number=10 ,can i used this variable inside the component

Comment: If you want to share variables between Angular1 directives and Angular2 components, you need to explicitly define them. I tried to do this implicitly with a directive that doesn't define its own scope and no input from the parent component, but it doesn't work...

Comment: what u mean by explicitly ..can u give some example? thank you

Comment: By explicit, I mean having the attribute defined for the isolated scope of the directive (within its scope attribute) and setting it when using the directive within the component. It's the sample I provided in my answer...